# Changing Map Tip popup direction dynamically

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, maptips

Is there a way to dynamically (or semi-automatic) change direction of a popup?

Default direction is 'right-down', which in some cases, where hovered feature is at the bottom of a canvas, Map Tip is cut (no. 3 on the image). So It would be better to have popup placed like no. 2.

I described only one case, but it applies to all situations, where features are close to border of a canvas.

[image]